# simplification of if equals (==) statement

Tags: ruby, if-statement, conditional-statements

How can i simplify the following if statement to remove the repetition?

```
if user.name == "john" && user.age > 10 or user.name == "wendy" && user.age > 10 or user.name == "mary" && user.age > 10
```

Thanks!

Comment: Use `||` instead of `or` for boolean expressions¡.

Comment: And for removing repetition of && you should just use `(user.name == "x" || user.name == "y") && user.age > 10` Apparently what @falsetru wrote is way better. I just said it so you try using `()` in your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [Array#include?](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-include-3F)

```
if ['john', 'wendy', 'mary'].include?(user.name) && user.age > 10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'set'

target_names = Set.new ["john", "wendy", "mary"]

if target_names.include? user.name and user.age > 10  ...
```